# Simple React with mySql fails to read table records

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I created a React project by entering the following command prompt commands

```
mkdir mysql-test && cd mysql-test
npm init –y
npm install mysql –save
```

Then I created a file called app.js and I put in the following code:

```js
    // app.js
       const mysql = require('mysql');

    // First you need to create a connection to the db
       const con = mysql.createConnection({
         host: 'rds-mysql-wmcw.cgz0te1dlkah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
         user: 'masterUsername',
         password: 'masterPassword',
         database : 'db_wmcw'
       });

    //try to connect to the mySql database.  If an error occurs, display an 
      error message on the console

       con.connect((err) => {
       if(err){
          console.log('Error connecting to Db');
          return;
        }

    //a connection has been established to the database.  Now, run a query against the table 'homepage'
    //to retrieve each row and all columns of the table
  
       console.log('Connection established');
       con.query('SELECT * FROM homepage', (err,rows) => {
       //if an error occurs when reading the data from the table, display the error on the console
    
       if(err) {
         console.log(err);
         return;
       }
  
    //data has been retrieved from the table.  display the data to the console

       console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
       console.log(rows);
       });
       });
       con.end((err) => {
      // The connection is terminated gracefully
      // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
      // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
    });
```

Before I added the `con.query` command, when I typed in `app.js` at the command prompt, the response back was Connection established. So I know that I am connecting to the `MySQL` database. When I include the `con.query` command, and type in `app.js` at the command prompt, I get the following error:

> Connection established { Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking
> quit.
> at Protocol._validateEnqueue (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:203:16)
> at Protocol._enqueue (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:138:13)
> at Connection.query (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:200:25)
> at Handshake.con.connect (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\app.js:21:7)
> at Handshake. (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
> at Handshake._callback (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:468:16)
> at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
> at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:92:8)
> at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
> at Parser.write (C:\jrs\codercamp\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
> code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false }

Right at the top of the error, it states `Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit`. I don't understand why the system thinks I am executing the query after invoking quit. I am not invoking quit unless that is what happens when I execute `con.end` but `con.end` is the last statement to execute.  It is way after the query call.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

PS - I have included the host name, user ID, password, and database name to make debugging easier.  There is no real important data in the database

Comment: Did you use server framework e.g. [express](https://expressjs.com/)?

Comment: I do not know so I would have to guess no.  I followed the instructions as I stated.  I got them from here: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

Comment: Sorry, I don't use it. I prefer use [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2). But, you should have basic understanding of using server framework. Don't hesitate to try express.

Comment: if I execute npm uninstall mysql, I should be able to execute npm install --save mysql2 and use the code as specified under First Query, right?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As the author said: `MySQL2 is mostly API compatible with mysqljs and supports majority of features`, it should do.

Comment: I uninstalled mysql and installed mySql2 and copied the sample text.  I am able to retrieve a row of data.  When I execute the console.log(results) line, I get [TextRow {product_title: 'xxxx', product_description: 'xxxxx'}] displayed.  How do I assign the product_title and product_description values to conts variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the alternative solution would be uninstall `mysql` package and change with `mysql2` package instead. As the author said:

> MySQL2 is mostly API compatible with mysqljs and supports majority of features

**This answer is for the questioner's comment on his post**

If you really wanna reassign the one row of data, you can do:

```
const { product_detail, product_description } = results[0];
```

That's basic syntax :D (ES6 maybe)